# How to delete Windows "locked" files?

Tags: windows, uti, anti-virus

My friend gave me a USB key that has Windows Viruses on it.

On my mac, when I try to delete them it fails and tells me that those files are "locked".
I ran an anti-virus, which also was unable to delete them for the same reason.

Comment: I think I found the answer. In the command line I typed "sudo rm filename".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options for files that came from a Windows drive:

1. Right click on the file and select "Get Info" (or mark all files and press `command` + `alt` + `i`) to get the file information. There in the "General"-tab you can find and opt-out the "Locked"-option. Trash and delete them.
2. Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and type `cd /Volumes/YourDrive`, then `rm -r thefile.exe`. If that fails, try `sudo rm -r thefile.exe` and enter your password.

Mac has other steps if you can't unlock the file - see [this article - TS1402](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1402) for details on immutable flags and if the directory permissions won't let you modify a file. The two above steps handle the vast majority of locked files on the mac.

Comment: I could not uncheck the "locked" option, but the "sudo" worked. Thanks